# CCSD and CISD size consistency problem

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, water, energy

I have performed a Gaussian16 calculation to explore the size-consistency problem for the CISD and CCSD methods. The system I am studying is the water dimer and the results are not what I expected at first. I have computed the energy of the dimer for both models (single point calculation) where the two monomers are 100 Å away and the energy of the and the energy of the monomer.

I wanted to compute the difference between those energies for both methods as two times the energy of the monomer and the energy of the dimer. If a method is size-consistent, the difference should be zero. These are my results:

$$
\begin{array}{lrr}
\hline
\text{Quantity}  & \text{CCSD} & \text{CISD} \\
\hline
\text{Monomer energy}/\pu{Ha}  & -75.012  & -75.012  \\
\text{Dimer energy}/\pu{Ha}    & -150.030 & -150.026 \\
\text{Abs. difference}/\pu{Ha} & 0.004    & 0.002    \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I have been reading many articles and papers and what I expected is that CISD is not size consistent for a system of more than two electrons while CCSD is size-consistent.

However, the value of the difference is larger in the case of CCSD, what makes me think that it is telling me that CCSD is less size-consistent for my problem than CISD. Am I wrong? What do these values mean?

Comment: When you write monomer energy, is it the true monomer energy, or did you use the "dimer" at 100 Angstrom distance?

Comment: It is the monomer energy, while the distance of the dimer is the energy of the dimer where the two monomers are 100 A away

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but you could opt to migrate this question to matter modelling SE. That site is specifically for computational modelling and there may be a better chance of an answer there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have already posted the question and can be found here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/cssd-and-cisd-self-consistency-problem